# Where would I ask a question about memorization techniques?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I am looking for a standard for memorizing tables, but there is no real fitting stack. I posted it in *english.stackexchange.com*, but it seems not to be the right public:
[words for numbers](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/115242/words-for-numbers)

Comment: I'm not sure if we have a memory training related site, I could not find one Area51 and from the top of my head. I could only find [Personal Productivity](http://productivity.stackexchange.com/) ***might*** be suitable but please ask on their Meta first.

Comment: Personal Productivity sounds like the best bet; their FAQ says that questions about "learning, memory and creativity" are within scope.

Comment: Ok, here we go: http://productivity.stackexchange.com/questions/7372/creative-common-system-to-memorize-1000-numbers-from-0-999

Comment: I'm confused by your question. This asks about memorization, and your posted question asks about data storage standards.

Comment: Okay, let's start at the beginning: What do you want to do?

Comment: i wanted to position the question in my last comment in the right place

Comment: @rubo77 and a note to readers, the question has been deleted and the link is now broken.